# Building a reusable D3.js chart in Angular with 100% width?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm building a D3.js bar chart directive in Angular, [based on this example](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/5372077).

It's working really well so far, but now I've hit a roadblock. I would like my chart to be a fluid width, not fixed, and set to 100% of the width of the containing element.

I know how to redraw the graph on resize in the directive:

```
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) { 
      var chartEl = d3.select(iElement[0]);
      window.onresize = function() {
          return scope.$apply();
      };
      scope.$watch(function(){
            return angular.element(window)[0].innerWidth;
        }, function(){
            chartEl.datum(scope.data).call(chart);
        }
      );
    }
```

This redraws the graph, but how do I pass the width of the window from the directive into the bar chart module, rather than using the fixed width of 500 pixels that is there at the moment? Do I need to attach the width to `data` or is there another way?

UPDATE: JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XCLR7/

Comment: Can you try to explain a bit more of what you mean? It looks like you are already updating the chart height whenever the height slider changes, why can't you do the same for width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested but this should work:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    chartEl.call(chart.width($(iElement[0]).width()));      
};
```

On resize: get the width, update the chart's width, and redraw the chart. Unless you need to display the chart's current width or use it outside of the chart, there isn't any reason to store the width in the scope or use a watch.

Answer (score 1):

I use this.offsetWidth where "this" is the div element. After a few iterations, here's what I ended up with. This works even if the width is updated with exports.width().

```
d3.custom.barChart = function module() {

  var width = 1000, // Update width in selection.each
      height = 500,
      widthFromElement = true,
      heightFromElement = true
  ...

  function exports(_selection) {
    _selection.each(function(_data) {

      width = widthFromElement ? this.offsetWidth || width : width
      height = heightFromElement ? this.offsetHeight || height : height
      ...
    })
  }

  ...

  exports.width = function(_x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    widthFromElement = false
    width = parseInt(_x);
    return this;
  };
```